# How to add dependency for custom facts -Facts['name'] executing first before all exec commands

Tags: puppet

Actually I am downloading list of files from ftp and from the downloaded path I am reading all the list of filenames for processing.

In `exec{"download from ftp ${value}"` I am downloading directories and sub directories with files from ftp to local. From that path am getting the list using custom facts `$facts['listdirectory']`

My problem is that `Facts['listdirectory']` is executed before being downloaded from ftp.

How to add dependency to `$datadir=$facts['listdirectory']` or how to make this facts get executed after download?

```
class classname{
    exec{"download from ftp ${value}":
        command => "wget -r --user=${ftp_username}  -- 
        password=${ftp_password}  ${value}/* -P ${patch_download_path}",
        path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
        timeout => 1800,
        user    =>'root',
    }
    $datadir=$facts['listdirectory']
}
```

Comment: my listdirectory.rb is lines = []
 Facter.add('listdirectory') do
   confine :kernel => "Linux"
   setcode do
   line= Facter::Core::Execution.execute('/bin/ls /exterro/services/jar_test/ ')

   lines=line.split(' ')

 lines
 end
 end

Comment: Please share the code for the facts instead of the Puppet resource using the facts.

Comment: listdirectory.rb lines = [] Facter.add('listdirectory') do confine :kernel => "Linux" setcode do line= Facter::Core::Execution.execute('/bin/ls /exterro/services/jar_test/ ') lines=line.split(' ') lines end end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that Facts['listdirectory'] is executed before being downloaded from ftp.

It looks like you mean that the fact's value is determined before *the directory contents*  (not the fact implementation) is downloaded.  Certainly that's what *will* happen, in any case.

All facts that will inform a given catalog-building run are evaluated first, then delivered as a group to the catalog builder (which typically runs remotely on a puppet master).  This gives the catalog builder a consistent snapshot of machine state to work from as it computes the desired target state by evaluating your manifests in light of the facts presented.  The result is delivered in the form of a catalog of classes and resources, which the local Puppet then applies.

Only at the catalog-application stage will the command specified by your `Exec` resource run.  This is after the whole catalog has been built, and long after fact evaluation.  If you want to adapt dynamically to what has been downloaded then you must either do so on the *next* Puppet run, or script it and run the script via the same or another `Exec` resource, or write a custom type and provider that encompass the whole process (probably including the download, too).